# How to write non English characters onto a webpage

Tags: html, character-encoding, non-english

I've been trying to write some non English characters on a web page, but I only see question marks after loading the page. Could anybody help me with doing this?

This is what I did.

```
<?php


$rr = 'Α,Β,Γ,Δ,Ε,Ζ,Η,Θ,Ι,Κ,Λ,Μ';
echo $rr


?>
```

and this is what the page displays

```
?,?,G,?,?,?,?,T,?,?,?,?
```

And trying this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<title>Untitled 2</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Α,Β,Γ,Δ,Ε,Ζ,Η,Θ,Ι,Κ,Λ,Μ</p>

</body>
</html>
```

also shows the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the charset UTF-8.

You can do this via header() from PHP or via meta tag inside your HTML.

PHP: `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');`

HTML5: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

HTML4: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

---

`test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled 2</title>
  </head>    
  <body>    
    <p>Α,Β,Γ,Δ,Ε,Ζ,Η,Θ,Ι,Κ,Λ,Μ</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ideone-DEMO: https://ideone.com/6vRqIc

As you can see in the DEMO i did not modify your PHP code.
The Ideone website is served with UTF-8 charset, so it works out of the box.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Just copy the content into a file `test.html`. Tested in FF and Chrome.

Comment: In which browser did you test this?

Comment: Ok. Which editor did you use to save the file? In which file encoding did you save the file?

Comment: Encoding Type =  ANSI,
Load as   = UTF-8,
File Format = DOS | Windows

Comment: I think the file is saved with the wrong encoding. You are using Notepad, right? Please open the file, then "Save as.." and under "Encoding" choose "UTF-8" and save the file. Then open the file in the browser. (Consider switching your editor to maybe Notepad++ or SublimeText and save your files as "UTF-8 without BOM".)

Comment: I am using  phpDesigner 8

Comment: It worked in Notepad with your directives. Thanks. But I use phpDesigner 8 for my programming works.

Comment: Glad i could help. (Sorry, i can't help with phpDesigner, becuase I don't know the product well enough, but saving a file in another encoding/charset should be possible.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I''ve done it. I can save all my scipts now with windows/utf-8 encoding ans all those characters appear nicely. Thanks once again.